# How to bind server response to a label in sencha touch 2.0?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, sencha-touch-2

In my app i have declared a label:-

```
 {
     xtype: 'label',
     id: 'errLabel',
     margin: '15 0 0 0'
 },
```

I want to display server response to the above label, for which I wrote a model and a store.
Now in my view i write the following code to add the server data to the label:-

```
 if(!this.strStore)
 {
      this.strStore = Ext.create('AGNSMS.store.logStore');
      console.log("strStore created");
 }

                   this.strStore.getProxy().setExtraParam({'UserId' : 
                  'XXXXXXX','Password' : 'XXXXXXX'});

                   var str = Ext.getCmp('errLabel');

                   str.setHtml('{MY_MODEL_FIELD}');
```

I know this not a right method.After click on login button label displays {MY_MODEL_FIELD} instead of real server data.So please suggest me something to display server response to the label.

Comment: Where exactly do you load your store ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the store after you set new params to the proxy, so I suggest you load your store with the `load()` function and then set the text of your label in the callback function:

```
this.strStore.getProxy().setExtraParam({'UserId' : 'XXXXXXX','Password' : 'XXXXXXX'});
one2one.stores.MeetingStore.load({
  scope   : this,
  callback: function(records, operation, success) {
    Ext.getCmp('errLabel').setHtml('SOME_TEXT');
  }
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i dont want to set any text at label.i want to display parsed server response at label and ur idea above is not working.it is giving the same result as previous.